# Array_sum of a fetch_row

Tags: php, database

I am attempting to get the summation of a set of float values in a column of a table. I did a select query that pulls five sets of integers. A **while** function with a **fetch_row** is used to get the array. I use a **foreach** function to get the sum, however, the echo or printf does not give me one single variable. Instead I get an ever increasing value as each integer is added to the summation of the values before it. I have tried the array_sum, which doesn't work either. Please help! I have looked at every possible question in Stackoverflow.

```
<?php 
//Check if at least one row is found
if($results2->num_rows > 0) {
    //Loop through results and fetch as an array                
    $total = 0;
    while($rows = $results2->fetch_row()){                      

        foreach($rows as $sum)

            $total += $sum;     

            printf($total.'<br/>');             
        }           
    }
?>
```

Comment: You might be interested in https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_sum

Comment: You've looked at every possible question in SO? That's unlikely. ;)

Comment: The `foreach` loop is looping over all the columns, not all the rows. Is that really what you want?

Comment: To elaborate on Barmar's comment, the variables in your current script should be named like this `while( $row=$results2->fetch_row() ){ foreach($row as $column) {` - also the 2 in `$results2` more often than not raises a red flag. YOu might want to show us a little more of your code.... (even though it will probably broaden the scope of the question)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're printing the total inside the loop, so you see all the subtotals. If you just want to see the final result, print it when the loop is done.

```
foreach ($rows as $sum) {
    $total += $sum;
}
printf("%d<br/>", $total);
```

Also, when you use `printf`, the first argument is a format string. The values come after, and they get substituted into the format.

You can also use `array_sum`:

```
printf("%d<br/>", array_sum($rows));
```

Note that these are summing up all the columns in each row, not a single column in the whole table.

Comment: IT WORKS!!! I'm teaching myself from scratch so certain concepts I have had to learn the hard way. THANK YOU! I wasn't getting the decimal places so I changed printf to print and it works perfectly! Thanks again!

Comment: You can use `%f` in `printf` to print floating point numbers.

Comment: But unless you need elaborate formatting control, `echo` is probably good enough